# TypeScript sorting an array with union type element

Tags: typescript

```
const list: ({ version: number, a: string }[]) | ({ version: number, b: string }[]) = [];

// Parameter 'a' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7006)
list.sort((a, b) => { 
    return a.version - b.version;
})
```

Why the parameters `a` and `b` are infer to `any`?

[TryIt](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2gLhgCgN4wG4FMBOEC4qYArgLYBGBANDAIarT4JgDmMAvgNoC6AShgAfdFjyFiYUpRr56VZlFYdu-IQF4Y-ANwAoPYmgA6CCHxQ0aBgs0A+GFj0wXMfLihl8YRsYlFwGABaGCo-AgCwfS4BAyA)

Comment: My guess is that you have a union type of two arrays, as opposed to an array of union types: `(A[] | B[])` vs `(A | B)[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you have a union *of arrays* which leads to the problem you observed down the line.

Let's make the code slightly clearer by naming the types. It will be a lot easier when discussing them later:

```js
type A = { version: number, a: string };
type B = { version: number, b: string };
```

So, what you have is `list: (A[] | B[])` as opposed to `(A | B)[]`. The two have different semantics - the latter does mean you can have mixed `A` and `B` types in a single array, while your only allows an array of only one. However, there is a difference in terms of typing.

TypeScript *does* recognise that all members of the union you have are arrays and thus `list.sort()` is an existing method. Actually, it's *two* methods - one comes from `A[]` the other from `B[]`. However, in order to ensure type safety, TypeScript will merge the signatures for both `.sort()` methods.

The signatures expects these callbacks to be passed in:

```
type sortA = (x: A, y: A) => number;
type sortB = (x: B, y: B) => number;
```

So, in order to merge the two, TypeScript will use

```
type mergedSort = sortA & sortB
```

This leads to problem - a function that implements `mergedSort` must accept `A`s or `B`s but never both at the same time. The only possible function that could do that will accept `any` type, since it satisfies the restrictions.

Hence, why you get the inferred type of `any` - it's the only one that can be used with either array.

By contrast, if you had `(A | B)[]` then the callback for the `.sort()` method would look like this:

```
type sortMixed = (x: A | B, y: A | B): number;
```

Since the types in the union share a `version` property, it would be valid to use it:

```js
type A = { version: number, a: string };
type B = { version: number, b: string };

const list: (A | B)[] = [];

list.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.version - b.version;
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUBuEBOBnAlgewDsAuKAgVwFsAjTAGigEMStgMcCBzKAXwG4AoUJCgAhBMjSZchEuWp0oVZq3Zc+-fgGNCLKABscLEgAo4AH1EBKANoBdcXYH8DLAHRY8GYMeMN6VSwQAPmR+KHCoDAhgMgwCRld0bHx4gFpFRKkUgW5LXiA)

Answer (score 0):

list can be either

```
{ version: number, a: string }[]
```

or

```
{ version: number, b: string }[]
```

which means if you only provide it with an empty array

```
list = []
```

it cant be sure of its type.

To fix it, simply tell typescript which one you're using:

```
const list: ({ version: number, a: string }[]) | ({ version: number, b: string }[]) = [];

// compiles
(list as ({ version: number, a: string }[])).sort((a, b) => { 
    return a.version - b.version;
})
```

Comment: On the contrary, TS knows *exactly* what the type is. It's either `{ version: number, a: string }[]` or `{ version: number, b: string }[]`. There is no confusion here.