# object[] | object[] type lacks a call signature for 'find(),foreach()'

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, types

I have two array variables with following interface:

```js
export interface IShop {
  name: string,
  id:   number,
  type: string,   
}

export interface IHotel {
  name: string,
  id:   number,
  rooms: number,   
}
```

My typescript code is as following:

```js
let shops: IShop[];
let hotels: IHotel[];
//these variables then gets assigned respective data from an API matching the interfaces

const allRegions = shops.length > 0 ? shops : (hotels.length > 0 ? hotels : []);

allRegions.find(r => r.name === 'name');
```

at the last line, I get error saying:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type
> '{ (predicate: (this: void, value: IShop, index:
> number, obj: IShop[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S; (predicate:
> (value:  IShop, index: number, obj: IShop[]) => boolean, thisArg?:
> any): IShop; } | { ...; }' has no compatible call signatures.

Same is happening for other Array methods during compilation, though code works fine and I know what the issue means but I am not clear on why Typscript is not recognizing the Array.

On typechecking `allRegion`, i get `IShop[] | IHotel[]` both of which are clearly arrays, is there something wrong with the datatype of `allRegion`?

Comment: inferred data types are tricky. why don't you just type it and end this?

Comment: Related: [TypeScript sorting an array with union type element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61121712)

Comment: Typing allRegion will be `allRegion: IShop[] | IHotel[]` to be correct according to the data and make the items of both objects available. But that's already getting assigned, is there a different way to combine both and extend it without creating a different interface?

Comment: You could just do `const region = shops.length > 0 ? shops.find(r => r.name === 'name') : (hotels.length > 0 ? hotels.find(r => r.name === 'name') : undefined);` I guess. No real need to assign `allRegions` as an intermediary. I'd use `if/else`, though, since I rather dislike the conditional operator, *especially* nesting multiple.

Comment: actually allRegion is used in a lot of other calculations as well, .find is just one of them and is async multi step so I can't combine all the calculations to a single place. I am trying answer in the link

Comment: Then I guess you can simplify to `const allRegions: (IShop | IHotel)[] = shops.length > 0 ? shops : hotels;` You lose some accuracy of the type signature but at least it's usable.

Comment: Thanks VLAZ for your time for helpful inputs. That can work but then I will need to check at every location on whether the array is empty or not. Kinda paradox of issues lol. @B45i's solution looks a bit patchy visually but worked with typescript compiler

Comment: "*then I will need to check at every location on whether the array is empty or not.*" how is that different to your current solution? Currently if the `shops` array is empty and the `hotels` array is empty, then you assign...an *empty array* to `allRegions`. Since you *only* assign an empty array if the `hotels` array is empty, it's effectively the same as assigning the empty `hotels` array. Unless you plan on doing mutations. If not, however, there is no real difference - an empty array is an empty array at the end. And you currently have that.

Comment: Yes the end result is same, seems more concise solution to me, Thank you @VLAZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem with method signature merging for union of arrays

The reason TypeScript complains is because with a type of `IShop[] | IHotel[]` it will merge all method signatures. In particular the signatures:

```typescript
Array<IShop>.find(
    predicate: (
        value: IShop, 
        index: number, 
        obj: IShop[]
    ) => unknown, thisArg?: any
): IShop | undefined

Array<IHotel>.find(
    predicate: (
        value: IHotel, 
        index: number, 
        obj: IHotel[]
    ) => unknown, thisArg?: any
): IHotel | undefined
```

Effectively becomes something similar to:

```typescript
Array<IShop & IHotel>.find(
    predicate: (
        value: IShop & IHotel, 
        index: number,
        obj: (IShop & IHotel)[]
    ) => unknown, thisArg?: any
): IShop & IHotel | undefined
```

This means that in order to call it, the callback should accept an item that's both `IShop` and `IHotel` at the same time and also will produce both an `IShop` and `IHotel` at the same time.

That's not actually possible, thus the compiler concludes that as the type signature is unsatisfiable, it is also uncallable.

This is a bit of a weakness in the way of how the method signatures are merged. It is the correct way to merge the signatures but for many use cases, the resulting types are not what you actually need, nor is the method call unsatisfiable. It's *more limited* in what can satisfy it but definitely not impossible:

```js
let shops = [{name: "shop1", id: 1, type: "supermarket"}];
let hotels = [{name: "hotel1", id: 2, rooms: 42}];

// see addendum
const allRegions = shops.length > 0 ? shops : hotels;

const result = allRegions.find(r => r.name === 'shop1');

console.log(result);
```

The issue is that this serves a more localised case and not the more general case where for any variation of calling the method.

The way to go around it is to use explicit typing which will allow you to retain type safety but you have to slightly override the compiler's decision.

## Possible solutions

### Change from a union of arrays, to an array of union type

Since `IShop[] | IHotel[]` (an array of `IShop` or array of `IHotel`) causes method signature merges that is uncallable, we can change the type to `(IShop | IHotel)[]` (an array of `IShop` and `IHotel` items). This is slightly incorrect, as you don't have a mixed array. However, there is almost no difference in practice. You still need to know what each item is, so it's very similar to having an array of either type.

What makes it work is that `IShop | IHotel` will allow you to use the shared properties between the two interfaces. In this case, `name` and `id`. Therefore, TypeScript will allow the call like `allRegions.find(r => r.name === 'name')`.

```typescript
const allRegions: (IShop | IHotel)[]  = shops.length > 0 ? shops : hotels;

allRegions.find(r => r.name === 'name'); //allowed
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQGUALCMOAbwCg44lMBbYALjgGcYpkBzAGhsQATVrSQBXBgCM0-WjACeYFu049etOFQC+VKqEixEKNFlwEAEhFQAbSgPpNWHLkj4CEwjeKkyBUCBAMbKze0lDqtNq6APTRMMTAbHgAbphcmJLWiXDxwEhw3MAwbHCYbGwI3EjAgnBQiUrYMAjJeIKYMJhw6P4MpfkAggAK+HAMHdjEPDkJRqgYOIlUgsDY1ml4WfBspGDBBCRkANoAugDcy6vr9XBbcKQ2+-iWNqcXVNgQSByl1tYASsBuAgvvsABREXZwAA+FiswGsAEpTrQALzsXZsAB0WVc8TgAD44AAGOAAfgxZBKrAeCLY70wf0BwNBWPQyEEYKgcFRRKgWIceFRwrgAHJBaLERcgA)

### Introduce a super type

Very similar to the above but you'd need to change your types:

```typescript
interface IDataItem {
  name: string,
  id:   number,
}

export interface IShop extends DataItem {
  type: string,   
}

export interface IHotel extends IDataItem {
  rooms: number,   
}
```

This is extracting the shared properties to an interface and then both `IShop` and `IHotel` extend it. This way you can more directly say that `allRegions` will contain the supertype. The result is essentially the same as the union type `IShop | IHotel` but made more explicit.

```typescript
const allRegions: IDataItem[]  = shops.length > 0 ? shops : hotels;

allRegions.find(r => r.name === 'name'); //allowed
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE5jqyBbZAbwChlkQ48IAuZAZzClAHMAaU5YAE1rJAFc8AI2jsAvsWIQAHgAcA9lDCdw0eEjQBlABbzZyGZBBc6aTNlwQCJMmACesmvUYtWZZMQlS5i5aEiwiCioABLykAA2BtJGJmZYOPhEHFDy8nh0tALCou6ekgD0BWDaEHQoAG5wTHBCEWXIJRAgyMwQYKZwdHTAzCAQXMhQZY4IYMAVKFwJyDCpBHAtAIIACqjIeFgI2iyNpSoB6mXEXBAIEdUo9cp0urKZWncA2gC6ANwnZxfDyNfIupEHqFwhAIq8PsQEPIQAxkHAIhEAEoQZjAaFA8yJKyvZAAXnodzoADp6iBmCVkAA+ZAABmQAH4CXpTLQAaC6BD4UiUWiYUSYKAuAAKKB46lQIkUKh43H4gDkUogcoAlB8gA)

If your data is actually related it might be preferable to represent that in your types. The type union does not convey the information about the relation. However, this still requires you to be able to change the types. If that's not a possibility, then a type union is the better option.

### Create a new union that will ensure usable array methods

As [a brilliant suggestion in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64599926/object-object-type-lacks-a-call-signature-for-find-foreach/64600004#comment114227748_64600680) from [Linda Paiste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10431574/linda-paiste):

> it's possible to declare `const allRegions: (IShop[] | IHotel[]) & (IShop | IHotel)[]` so that we get the union signature without losing the restriction that the array elements are of the same type.

Which will give you this:

```typescript
const allRegions: (IShop[] | IHotel[]) & (IShop | IHotel)[] = shops.length > 0 ? shops : hotels;

allRegions.find(r => r.name === 'name'); //allowed
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQGUALCMOAbwCg44lMBbYALjgGcYpkBzAGhsQATVrSQBXBgCM0-WjACeYFu049etOFQC+VKqEixEKNFlwEAEhFQAbSgPpNWHLkj4CEwjeKkyBUCBAMbKze0lDqtNq6APTRMMTAbHgAbphcmJLWiXDxwEhw3MAwbHCYbGwI3EjAgnBQiUrYMAjJeIKYMJhw6P4MpfkAggAK+HAMHdjEPDkJRqgYOIlUgsDY1ml4WfBspGDBBCRkANoAugDcy6vr9XBbcKQ2+-iWNqcXVNgQSByl1tYASsBuAgvvsABREXanOAAHwsVmA1lOAEo4AAyOAQw7kOHPBHWZHQgC87F2bAAdFlXPE4AA+OAABjgAH5SWQSqwHoi2O9MH9AcDQeT0MhBGCoHAifSoOSHHgiQq4AByOVK5FnOCxPnWCAAdxqQA)

This is an intersection between two homogenous arrays and a mixed array.

This declaration resolves to `(IShop[] & (IShop | IHotel)[]) | (IHotel[] & (IShop | IHotel)[])` which is a union of

- homogenous `IShop` array intersected with a mixed `IShop | IHotel` array
- homogenous `IHotel` array intersected with a mixed `IShop | IHotel` array

The brilliant part is that it behaves exactly the same as `IShop[] | IHotel[]` - you cannot have a mix. However, at the same time, the type will ensure the method declaration merge works correctly. This means that you get correct type checks for arrays that only have one type of item in them but not mixed:

```typescript
declare let shops: IShop[];
declare let hotels: IHotel[];
//mixed array
declare let mixed: (IShop | IHotel)[];
//homogenous array of either type
declare let improved: (IShop[] | IHotel[]) & (IShop | IHotel)[];

//something that takes a homogenous array
declare function foo(x: IShop[] | IHotel[]): void;

foo(shops);    //ok
foo(hotels);   //ok
foo(mixed);    //error
foo(improved); //ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQGUALCMOAbwCg44lMBbYALjgGcYpkBzAGhsQATVrSQBXBgCM0-WjACeYFu049etOFQC+VKqEixEKNFlwEAEhFQAbSgPpNWHLkj4CEwjeKkyBUCBAMbKze0lDqtNq6gsDY1phQeNbA8GykYMEEJGQA2gC6ANxUMXEJSSlwpDaZ+JY2+UUA9I0MCCDAgnAJUJjyxbHxiXDYEEgccK3tngAUROlwAD4WVsDWAJQNVM2kDBDcwEgQYmxdUD3ycBDocMAIMMRocApK-aVDI2PwCAxg-gBuHVYs2yYHyi2W9TyazgADI4MD5ktait1psto02IEUsQeE9iJh4DBMABrYAnTCVQJ7A5HclnXqvQZ4dBiJDYGAIUZwdABaYgVhzXJ5cHIyFrVh-CAeIpUHkQaZpMhsNYFDRwZoQYmy3lVVbK1W0DVauXTSYdFVq5pofxQbXy76-CAAwQWo1AA)

## Addendum: clarifying with `allRegions` initialisation

The line `const allRegions = shops.length > 0 ? shops : (hotels.length > 0 ? hotels : [])` is superfluous. You only assign an empty array to `allRegions` is `hotels` is an empty array (and `shops` too). Since an empty array is an empty array either case, you can shorten this to `const allRegions = shops.length > 0 ? shops : hotels` - if `hotels` is empty, you an empty array anyway. This is what I've used in the code samples above as it makes the code a lot easier to read.

It has the exact same effect as long as you don't plan on mutating the array in-place. That might modify the wrong array.

Comment: This is an excellent answer.  If I can suggest one tiny improvement/clarification RE: the union types, it's possible to declare `const allRegions: (IShop[] | IHotel[]) & (IShop | IHotel)[]` so that we get the union signature without losing the restriction that the array elements are of the same type.

Comment: This is an excellent answer.  If I can suggest one tiny improvement/clarification RE: the union types, it's possible to declare `const allRegions: (IShop[] | IHotel[]) & (IShop | IHotel)[]` so that we get the union signature without losing the restriction that the array elements are of the same type.

Comment: @LindaPaiste this is *brilliant*! I never thought about using this declaration but you're right - it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score -2):

Add Explicit typing to `allRegions`, You are getting this error because ht empty array that you are passing at the end of the condition don't have any type.

```js
const allRegions: IShop[] |  IHotel[] | any[]  = shops.length > 0 ? shops : (hotels.length > 0 ? hotels : []);
```

[Fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQGUALCMOAbwFgAoOOJTAW2AC44BnGKZAcwBpa9BABN29JAFcmAIzSC6cGAE8wbTtz796cWgF9atUJFiIUaLLgIAJCKgA2lIQ2bquPJAOejxDaXKgFeigICCYOdilZeR19Qxp7YHgOUjAIghIyAG0AXTgAXjhcgG5aRPhSB3T8WwdcgqKc0poAehaYYmAOPAA3TB5MGUSOJU6kOF4kkcwODgReJGAROCgutWwYBB68EUwYTDh0EKY4THGAQQAFfDgmPexiPlG8ZFQMHC74nW%20f37--gGAoE6NpEVLAwGg2rARxwNpnZS5WjYCBILinez2ABKwF4CFR1UyYHqAB96DU7DDSackIi8g0UmQOAA6RKeDpwAB8cAADHAAPycVIjdgACkqMJZbN4HO5fMFEvsIsaAEpmrRMJicXiCcz0MgRKKoAVuVBmYwWAV8oUAOQW4A2tVAA)

Comment: The `any[]` is a very bad idea. It's just a nasty trick to get TS to use the merged declaration for these. There is no need to add it - it's not accurate and it's likely to throw people off. Not to mention throwing the compiler off - now `allRegions.find(r => r.foobar === 'name');` is a legal thing to use. I don't see the value of throwing away type safety and clarity of the code. You may as well have cast the entire thing to `any[]` as that's the effective signature right now.

Comment: It's still an array. Either `IShop[]` or `IHotel[]` is still correct. Besides, the problem isn't with the empty array - TS correctly infers the type to be `IShop[] | IHotel[]`, so there is no real reason to add an "empty array type". The problem is that TS will merge the method signatures for *both* arrays and this results in a signature that isn't callable, as it is unsatisfiable - it needs to work *both* with `IShop` + `IShop[]` and `IHotel` + `IHotel[]` at the same time, which is not possible to exist.