# Correct way to define Array Union Types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Can someone explain are those 2 array union types identical?
And if they are not the same, what would be the correct use case for each one?

```
const a: string[] | number[] = [];
const b: (string|number)[] = []
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [object\[\] | object\[\] type lacks a call signature for 'find(),foreach()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64599926/object-object-type-lacks-a-call-signature-for-find-foreach)

Comment: I assume you mean `b: (string | number)[]` because `string|number[]` means either a string as a plain value or an array of numbers.

Comment: Yes Vlaz, exactly I mean b: (string | number)[]. Will update the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not identical. Here is the difference:

> `const a: string[] | number[] = [];`

This means that `a` can be `array of strings` or `array of numbers`. So:

```
// Array of strings
a = ['h', 'e'];
// or Array of numbers 
a = [1, 2];
```

> `const a: string|number[] = []`

Means that `a` is either a `string` OR `an array of numbers`

```
// string
a = 'hello';
// or array of numbers
a = [1, 2];
```

> `const a: (string|number)[] = []`

Means that `a` is an array where each item in the array can be a `number` or a `string` so:

```
// (string | number) array
a = ['h', 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

`b` is a string **or** an array of `number`. Therefore these are not identical. `b` could be written as `const b: (string | number)[] = [];`. However, this allows mixed types like `const b: (string | number)[] = [1, 'a'];`, which `a` does not.