# Confusion about TypeScript Union Types

Tags: typescript, union-types

I want a certain property of an object (`groupItems`) to be either an array of strings or an array of objects so I created the below interface:

```
 interface PanelItem {
      groupTitle: string;
      groupItems: string[] | {text: string, type: string}[];
    }
```

I created a TypeScript variable `panelContent: PanelItem[] = []` and tried adding items to it like

```
this.panelContent.push({groupTitle: 'abc', groupItems: ['item3', {text: 'item', type: 'action'}, 'item4']});
```

But TypeScript complains about this saying

```
TS2322: Type '(string | { text: string; type: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'string[] | { text: string; type: string; }[]'. 
  Type '(string | { text: string; type: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'. 
    Type 'string | { text: string; type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'. 
      Type '{ text: string; type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

So I changed the interface to

```
 interface PanelItem {
          groupTitle: string;
          groupItems: (string | {text: string, type: 'action'})[];
        }
```

and TypeScript no longer complains.
Can someone please explain the difference between these two interface syntaxes?

Comment: `A[]|B[]` is either an array of all `A` or all `B` while `(A|B)[]` is an array of either A or B in each entry (so the latter can be a mix of A and B in the array the former is purely one or the other)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [object\[\] | object\[\] type lacks a call signature for 'find(),foreach()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64599926/object-object-type-lacks-a-call-signature-for-find-foreach)

Comment: @VLAZ  I read your answer to that question. While I understood some things, I didn't understand how it answers my question exactly. Maybe it's just my limited understanding of TS.

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks! Your comment actually made things much clearer.