# TypeScript: Reduce an array of objects that could have either one or another type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need help with the following situation:

```
type Primary = {
  name?: string;
  display_name?: string;
  git?: { branch?: string };
};

type Secondary = {
  name?: string;
  git?: { branch?: string };
  size?: number;
};

const reduceFunction = (arr: Primary[] | Secondary[] | undefined) =>
  arr?.reduce((previous, current) => {
    if (current?.git?.branch) {
      const newBranchObject = {
        ...previous,
      };
      newBranchObject[current.git.branch] = previous[current.git.branch] || [];
      newBranchObject[current.git.branch].push(current);
      return newBranchObject;
    }
    return previous;
  }, {});
```

Reduce is underlined red, telling me

> This expression is not callable.
> Each member of the union type '{ (callbackfn: (previousValue: Primary, currentValue: Primary, currentIndex: number, array: Primary[]) => Primary): Primary; (callbackfn: (previousValue: Primary, currentValue: Primary, currentIndex: number, array: Primary[]) => Primary, initialValue: Primary): Primary; (callbackfn: (previousValue: U, currentValu...' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.

What does that even mean? Do I need to solve this with a generic and if so, how? Thanks a lot for any hint!

It works with

```
Primary[] | undefined
```

but I don't know how to use it if the type could be either

```
Primary[] | Secondary[] | undefined
```

Comment: To properly express that the array is of *either* `Primary` *or* `Secondary` but not a mix, you can use `((Primary[] | Secondary[]) & (Primary | Secondary)[]`  See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64600680

Comment: The problem is that unions of generic methods are hard to call; the currently open issue for this is [ms/TS#44373](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44373) and the workaround is generally to widen `A[] | B[]` to `readonly (A | B)[]` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WzP1EN). Note that I also had to define the type of the initial object as `Record<string, (Primary | Secondary)[]>` in order for it to work.  Does that address your question fully? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, both anwers are very helpful. I have an additional one if I may: Let's say that in `Primary` the `git` property is called `gitData`. And I would check in the reduce: `const currentGit = current?.gitB?.branch || current?.git?.branch;` and then replace all the occurences of `current.git.branch` with the variable `currentGit`. It will underline `gitData` and `git` because it is not present on the other type. Thanks so much for your help with this!